# The castle is under attack $-$ where does the chambermaid run?

Tags: medieval, royalty, fortifications

In my story, there is a high level servant that I need to become aware that the area is under attack. I want her to be in her private quarters when it happens, then run toward wherever the duke and duchess would probably be, or where other important friends of hers would be. (That part of the story isn't set in stone yet). I originally wrote it that she was in a palace and ran toward the keep, but I started to think this didn't make a lot of sense.

Where should I have her quarters? Where should I make her destination when she begins running?

The tag wiki for [middle-ages] suggests I narrow down the timeframe. I really don't care too much, but if it makes a huge difference, let's go with Late-Middle-Ages.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to determine to add realism to her story, but there are too many variables.  If you want her a long way away then she is in her family's home in the town or village outside the castle walls.  If you want her really close then the castle is under siege and she is squeezed into a room nearby, or the duchess wants her on standby all the time and she's in a small room right next door.  Decide where you want her to suit your story and ask a reality check question on your concept is probably the best option, near-infinite possible answers as written.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is *at best* a historic question. Not world building. But I don't even think it's really that historic, either - servants would have lived in the same house as their masters or nearby (servant's house) or even not on the property (in a house outside the walls). Where one specific servant would be would vary. In time, place, who they even serve. Moreover, what one specific servant would do in an attack isn't worldbuilding either. It's story and character motivation. Very loyal one might run to help the masters. Another might run in the opposite direction. Might even try to help attackers.

Comment: In one fairly famous historical case, a Byzantine emperor was overthrown. The [Varangian Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varangian_Guard) decided that since they served the throne, not a person, so they didn't owe loyalty to individuals. So, there was no reason to help the *very* recently deposed person and instead went with the very recently self-proclaimed emperor. Varangians aren't your typical example of servants but aren't too far off, either. They would follow their interests (mostly money) rather than politics. Many servants would likely do the same.

Comment: @VLAZ you are probably correct that putting this question here is a stretch. My thought was that I was building the environment around the castle / keep.

Comment: Closed for being "story-based", because where they might run is simply dependent on how the attack is done, in other words how the enemy generals "choose" to make the surprise attack, the only situation you'd need to "run" (or they're very incompetent ^^). The fact you're asking two questions and the lack of spatial sense of how the castle is designed and where it is relative to the village doesn't help, either. To solve this I think the best idea is to ask a [tag:internal-consistency] question instead, as KerrAvaon2055 suggested.

Answer (score 3):

**Basement**

[image]

> Where should I have her quarters?

[Windsor Castle put at least some of the domestic servants in the basement.](https://www.rct.uk/about/future-programme/news-and-features/the-undercroft-at-windsor-castle#/)

The servants' quarters were close to the royal living area because the kitchen needed to be close to the dining room. Then you may as well put the rest of the servants' quarters beside the kitchen for convenience.

I suspect a high ranking servant like a butler would have their own room and the lower servants sleep in dormitories.

For more detail I suggest you pick a castle similar to the one in your story and try to find the historical floorplans.

> Where should I make her destination when she begins running?

I suggest she starts in one of the rooms cleaning it and when she sees fighting out the window, and realizes the walls are breached she runs to the basement and the servants barricade themselves inside. If there are baddies in the keep then the castle has already fallen, and no one is coming to save the servants.

Answer (score 3):

In the old times the attic was the place for the servants, because right under the roof was more exposed to the weather (rain, heat and cold would more easily seep through the not weathertight roof) making it a place where no respectable noble would want to reside.

Moreover, in the very likely event of a fire breaching out in the building, the closer one was to the ground level, the better for ensuring a quick escape: less risk of having wooden frame and stairs engulfed in fire during the run for life. And of course the life of the nobles were more considered than those of the servants when it came to save them.

Comment: I suggest the basement and you suggest the attic. Compromise and put the servants in the middle floor.